# Can we alter a table in Glue?

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

If i am using Glue as a metastore, is it possible to alter any existing table (Like adding a new column or changing the data type of column) in it ?
The only way  I could find was deleting the existing table and then creating a new table with the changed schema.
Please help if there is a way to modify existing table itself.

Edit - I mean to ask to update the schema via Glue API and not via AWS Glue UI as I could only find API to Create or Drop the table but not alter the table.

Comment: First select your table from table menu, there will be **Edit Schema** Option at top of right side, here you can Add Column and change any column name or data type, you can also configure your crawler to change table schema according to input files.

Comment: @AchyutVyas I am sorry not being thorough in my question. What i actually meant to ask was, if it is possible to alter the schema of table through API. As I could only find was deleting the table or creating the table. But not altering the table.

Comment: will you please look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_UpdateTable.html), although I haven't tested it.

Comment: @RahulSharma have you figured out the solution? I have the same problem now.

Comment: @RoyalTiger I have updated it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Update:
I was able to do this by using AWS Java SDK.
First create a AWS Glue Client based on your configuration.
Given an example here -
https://www.edureka.co/community/1490/how-do-i-get-my-aws-glue-client-in-java

After we have created the AWS Glue client,we can invoke updateTable() method on it to update an existing Table.
Below is the signature of same -

```
UpdateTableResult updateTable(UpdateTableRequest updateTableRequest);
```

Here UpdateTableRequest is nothing but an AmazonWebServiceRequest which is created using some basic parameters like Table Name, Catalog Id, Input schema etc.
You can check out this url to get sample example -
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-data-catalog-replication-utility/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/gdcreplication/util/GlueUtil.java

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Do you have linkedin profile ? Can you please share?

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have seen updateTable() method in GlueServiceImp.java . This takes "String databaseName, String tableName, List<Column> columns, List<Column> partitionKeys" as input. I believe I have to pass all the columns along with the new one in the column field. My question have you handled the existing data for the newly added columns in the table? have you run any migration job?

Comment: @RoyalTiger Sorry, No I have not worked on any such migration job.